# On clicking the submit button of a form, it's not responding

Tags: php, html, forms, web, form-submit

Form submit button is not responding even though I have specified the action, in the form action field.

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="php/record.php">
    <h3>Enter the following details :</h3>

    <form autocomplete="off" action="">
        <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
            <label for="school">School :</label> <br>
          <input id="school" type="text" name="School" placeholder="Enter School" required>
        </div>
      </form>
        <br>
        
        <form autocomplete="off" action="">
        <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
            <label for="school_ID">School ID :</label> <br>
          <input id="school_ID" type="text" name="School_ID" placeholder="Enter School ID" required>
        </div>
      </form>
        <br>
        

        <label for="class">Class :</label>
        <select name="Class" id="class">
        <option value="I">I</option>
        <option value="II">II</option>
        <option value="III">III</option>
        <option value="IV">IV</option>
        <option value="V">V</option>
    </select>
 <label for="sec">Sec : </label>
 <select name="sec" id="sec">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
 </select>

        <br><br>

        <label for="Film_1">Film 1 :</label> <br>
        <input id = "Film_1" type= "text" placeholder="Enter film 1" name="Film_1" required>   
        <br>
<br>
  
        <label for="Film_2">Film 2 (if applicable) :</label><br>
        <input id = "Film_2" type="text" placeholder="Enter film 2" name="Film_2">
        <br>
<br>

        <label for="Film_3">Film 3 (if applicable) :</label><br>
        <input id = "Film_3" type="text" placeholder="Enter film 3" name="Film_3">
        <br>
<br>

        <button id="submit_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>

        <input name="Picture" type="file" onchange="readURL(this)" accept="image/*">
    </form>
</div>    

</body>
```

Please suggest me where I'm going wrong in my code as nothing is happening on clicking the submit button. I want to redirect to another page i.e. record.php on clicking submit

Comment: The `for` attribute for a `<label>` needs to match the `id` of a form control. At least one of yours matches a `name` (on an element which has a different `id`) and one doesn't seem to match anything at all.

Comment: I've made the required changes, still no response. I've also changed the type to "submit" instead of "button"

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <button id="submit_btn" type="button">Submit</button>
> ```

That isn't a submit button.

A submit button has `type="submit"` (or no `type` attribute at all as `submit` is the default value).

`type="button"` is used for buttons which has no default behaviour (i.e. when you want to add behaviour using JavaScript).

> ```
> <form action="php/record.php">
>     <h3>Enter the following details :</h3>
>
>     <form autocomplete="off" action="">
> ```

Forms may not be nested. Write valid HTML. Remove the extra form.

Comment: still no response after changing the type as submit

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a submit button.

Change

```
<button id="submit_btn" type="button">Submit</button>
```

To

```
<button id="submit_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Also you have several forms nested, which isn't allowed and can also cause your browser to behave unexpected

Comment: still no response

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in the code.
you can use that code.

```
<div class="container">
<form action="php/record.php">
<h3>Enter the following details :</h3>
    <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <label for="school">School :</label> <br>
      <input id="school" type="text" name="School" placeholder="Enter School" required>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <label for="school_ID">School ID :</label> <br>
      <input id="school_ID" type="text" name="School_ID" placeholder="Enter School ID" required>
    </div>
    <br>
    

    <label for="class">Class :</label>
    <select name="Class" id="class">
    <option value="I">I</option>
    <option value="II">II</option>
    <option value="III">III</option>
    <option value="IV">IV</option>
    <option value="V">V</option>
    </select>

    <label for="sec">Sec : </label>
    <select name="sec" id="sec">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>

    <label for="Film_1">Film 1 :</label> <br>
    <input id = "Film_1" type= "text" placeholder="Enter film 1" name="Film_1" required>   
    <br>
<br>

    <label for="Film_2">Film 2 (if applicable) :</label><br>
    <input id = "Film_2" type="text" placeholder="Enter film 2" name="Film_2">
    <br>
<br>

    <label for="Film_3">Film 3 (if applicable) :</label><br>
    <input id = "Film_3" type="text" placeholder="Enter film 3" name="Film_3">
    <br>
<br>

    <input name="Picture" type="file" onchange="readURL(this)" accept="image/*">
    <button id="submit_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).